# Add UI feedback when successfully flagging a comment

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags, flag-dialog

When flagging a comment for *some* reason, no tooltip appears to say "Thanks, we'll take a look" or similar upon submitting the flag... just... *nothing*.

Can you please add such a feedback so we know the flag did not fail and went on its merry way?

Comment: I don't recall seeing such feedback, just the vote arrow and flag icon not showing anymore. Anyway you can track the flag process in the flag summary page.

Comment: @Sha: It's more about the "is this still loading?", "did it fail?" side of things...

Comment: Hmm.. good point but it might be a feature request rather than a bug. :)

Comment: There's never been any feedback message after successfully adding a comment flag, only when an error occurs... perhaps we should add one.

Comment: @Jarrod so [meta-tag:status-planned] then? ;)